# Options for playing music wirelessly from iPod touch and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

What are the options for playing music from an iPod touch over speakers in multiple rooms, preferably with the ability to turn speakers off in a specific room using a remote? I currently have a basic stereo system but it's about 5 years old, only has two speakers, and doesn't support Bluetooth so I'm not sure if it's worth trying to use with the iPod for this type of setup. Cost isn’t an issue at least until I figure out what the options are.

Comment: It's really never too late to accept an answer or edit a question to help someone get you the answer you seek...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my speaker system is hooked up to my desktop computer I use [Shairport4w](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shairport4w/) to airplay music and podcasts from my iphone to my desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Today Apple announced that the upcoming iOS 4.2 update coming in November will contain a feature called [AirPlay](http://www.engadget.com/2010/09/01/apple-demoes-ios-4-2-for-the-ipad-not-shipping-yet/) where you can stream music, video, and photos directly from your iOS device to a new Apple TV (and presumably the Airport Express).

Comment: To add to this answer, I'd just like to say you can buy a BlackBerry Stereo Gateway, which Bluetooths to your device and then sends all sound to the attached speaker. I use it at school for playing our Drama play's music and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your stereo has an audio in port, you can go with an Airport Express and send the music wirelessly from iTunes/Front Row on your computer.

http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/features/airtunes.html

You could use your iPhone/iPod as a remote using Apple's free Remote app.

I hope this helps.